# Django models: set value before saving

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a model for which I would be able to set a value automatically before saving it to the database... so far I did override `save()` in this way:

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
    if not self.paramX:
        self.paramX = value
    super(Post, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```

Anyway, this does not work using `bulk_create()`... what can I do? (I'm trying using Signals but with no luck)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract from the documentation : (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create)

> The model’s save() method will not be called, and the pre_save and post_save signals will not be sent.

It is because the bulk saving method use an other way to save the data. And so a way is to manually do it as you create each entry to insert.

Answer (score 0):

My preference would be the following:

```
class Instrument(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Instrument, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.name = "Bass"
```

**Edit:**

I just re-read your question. If you're only concerned with whether or not the *“paramX”* field is set upon saving, couldn't you just add a *“default”* to the model field? i.e.

```
class Instrument(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="No instrument")
```

Comment: unfortunately Matt, I can't use "default", since the value is computed based on another field of the same model :P